Extract element in STRUCT data type Redshift Spectrum
I have a spectrum table with the following schema:
TABLE spectrum.table (
    realmcode struct < @code: string >,
    typeid struct < @extension: string,
    @root: string >,
    templateid struct < @root: string >,
    id struct < @assigningAuthorityName: string,
    @extension: string,
    root: string >
) 

I would like to extract the assigningAuthorityName field id  struct
Example:
{"@assigningauthorityname":"BBBB","@extension":"CCCC","@root":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.9.4.3.8"}
I run the following sql
SELECT  c.id.@assigningAuthorityName
 FROM "spectrum"."table" c

and it gives me "syntax error at or near "@" in context ".id.@"
If i run
SELECT  c.id.assigningAuthorityName
 FROM "spectrum"."table" c

**and it retuns me a NULL value
**
How can I solve it ?
Thank you

Wrap it in quotes, just like if it had a capitol letter in it
SELECT  c.id.”@assigningAuthorityName”
 FROM "spectrum"."table" c

